# Source of picture - Vocal apparatus

Tags: phonology, reference-request, spoken-language

I hope it is not inadequate to ask this type of question but I would really like to know the source of the following image:

[image]

It is the ,,aparato fonador" and I do not search for similar images but for the source of this exact image. My professor used it and he said that the script is from 2010 and not his script so he does not know the source either. (I think it may be Quilis but I don't know which book.)

Comment: It's a fairly generic schema of the vocal tract; I've seen this in countless phonetics and linguistics textbooks for literally decades. But it doesn't reflect well on yout professor that he uses images without attribution or knowledge of the source...